# Flutter uncheck Checkbox if other checkbox is checked

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter code where I want to have all the other checkboxes unchecked if a checkbox is checked. I don't want to use radio buttons. How can I do that?
I also don't know how I can access the bool of the other Widgets when I am in a Widget (e.g. in OptionOneCheckbox, how can I access the bool isChecked in the OptionTwoCheckbox/OptionThreeCheckbox Widget?).

This is the code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OptionOneCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OptionOneCheckboxState createState() => _OptionOneCheckboxState();
}

class _OptionOneCheckboxState extends State<OptionOneCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class OptionTwoCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OptionTwoCheckboxState createState() => _OptionTwoCheckboxState();
}

class _OptionTwoCheckboxState extends State<OptionTwoCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        checkColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            isChecked = value;
          });
        });
  }
}

class OptionThreeCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OptionThreeCheckboxState createState() => _OptionThreeCheckboxState();
}

class _OptionThreeCheckboxState extends State<OptionThreeCheckbox> {
  bool isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Checkbox(
        checkColor: Colors.white,
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            isChecked = value;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it works with my testing I tested it with a `List<String>`. Instead of setting a bool value in `onChange` you set a `String` and then test if that is the string that is selected if not it if `false` pretty simple.

```
String selected;

ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...list.map(
              (listValue) => CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(listValue),
                value: listValue == selected,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selected = listValue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Let me know if you have any problems